# store user_id in the backend automatically depending on user type in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables in my database..one is candidates_details and another one is users..in the users table i have two types of users one is vendor and another one is user..they both have same user_id column...and i have that user_id column in my candidates_details table..

So what i want to do is when vendor post candidate_details by using form ..i want to store that user_id

> (where user_type_id=1)

in candidates_details table automatically..

Can anyone help me..Thanks in advance..

Comment: just fetch the id you want and pass it as a hidden variable in the form..and insert in database

Comment: yes..but my problem is i already get user first names from users table in form..so when vendor insert candidate details they can select user name from drop down..when they select i store that  user_id in db..

Comment: that user_id is type 2..so i want to store vendor id also where user_type_id is  2.i want to store both id's..but they both have same column user_id in users table

Comment: @VimalS you understand right?what i am excatly looking for..

Comment: not exactly..paste your code also in the question

Comment: @VimalS  simply..i want to store both(vendor and user_id)  id's in user_id column..

Comment: @bharathi you need to work on your db schema. Saving ids serving different purposes in one column is not a good idea. if you have two different user roles or user types , you can write a function like getUserTypeId($id) and get that id dynamically in your controller and then send that to your model to save it in database

Comment: yes @MalikMudassar but my requirement is like that only..is there any way to solve this..

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you out by giving a pictorial example. Assume you have two tables users and candidate_details. In users you are keeping record of all the registered users along with their types. In Candidate Details you are keeping their profile data. You create another table where you keep user types Be it vendor, contractor, supplier etc.

Now when you create your form to post data in your admin panel or which ever interface you have. Just create a dropdown for user_types, get the type id and add the user. With the type id in your users table you can easily query which type of user that is.

Now for saving that user's profile information in candidate_details table you only have to provide user_id. So creating one more table will normalize your db schema and saves a lot of hustle in your query building.

[image]

Comment: i have like that only in my db..but the problem is here when vendor insert values in candidate form i gave one drop down for vendor..in that i display all the users(user_type_id is user)..depending on that user i store that user_id in db..and as well as i send a mail to that particular user..with all candidate_details..

Comment: so the problem here is the candidate from is inserted by vendor only right?so i want to insert that user_id(vendor) in candidate_details table so by that user know this candidate details coming form this vendor..

Comment: can you please share fields of users table and candidate_detail table